# How to define that float is half of the number?

Tags: php, floating-point, numbers

What would be the most efficient way to say that float value is half of integer for example 0.5, 1.5, 10.5?

First what coming on my mind is:

```
$is_half = (($number - floor($number)) === 0.5);
```

Is there any better solutions?

Comment: **Never** compare using equality on floating point numbers. There is an inherited imprecision.

Comment: @poke: 0.5 is representable exactly as a float, so there shouldn't be a problem until the integers get very large.

Comment: @Michael: And if the integer part gets that large, the decimal point won't even be stored anymore due to lack of precision...  So for all floats that have a .5 after the decimal point, it'll be an exact representation...

Comment: I did'n know about such issues, however main usage of this operations is to display time value for example one hour and half, two hours and half etc.

Comment: @poke I don't understand what's wrong with comparing two floats, for example M_PI === 0.5?

Comment: @Nazariy: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems – also, when you want to store time (and compare it later) then don't store it as float hours. Instead store the time in minutes (or seconds if you need the precision) or even use a unix timestamp (which gives you additional language function support).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Due to floating point precision errors, you usually should check to see that the difference is below some low amount (but note that `0.5` is representable exactly, so it shouldn't be a problem, but it is in general with floats).

So your code is good for your specific sense, in general, you might want to do:

```
if (abs($number - floor($number) - $decimal) < 0.0001) {
```

Where `$decimal` is your looking difference: `0.5`.

Comment: How is the $number determined to be half of integer then?

Answer (score 0):

```
if(abs($number) - (int)(abs($number)) == 0.5) {
    // half of an integer.
}
```