# How to define a function that returns half of input, in two different ways?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I am reading a Gentle Introduction to Symbolic Computation and it asks this question. Basically, the previous content deals with making up bigger functions with small ones. (Like 2- will be made of two 1- (decrement operators for lisp))

So one of the questions is what are the two different ways to define a function HALF which returns one half of its input. I have been able to come up with the obvious one (dividing number by 2) but then get stuck. I was thinking of subtracting HALF of the number from itself to get half but then the first half also has to be calculated...(I don't think the author intended to introduce recursion so soon in the book, so I am most probably wrong).

So my question is what is the other way? And are there only two ways?

EDIT : Example HALF(5) gives 2.5

P.S - the book deals with teaching LISP of which I know nothing about but apparently has a specific bent towards using smaller blocks to build bigger ones, so please try to answer using that approach.

P.P.S - I found this so far, but it is on a completely different topic - [How to define that float is half of the number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4769388/how-to-define-that-float-is-half-of-the-number)
Pdf of book available here - http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~dst/LispBook/book.pdf (ctrl+f "two different ways")

Comment: I'm not sure whether it is allowed in lisp but you can bit shift towards right by 1.

Comment: @AbhishekBansal This is the absolute beginner chapter, so the answer is probably not it.

Comment: Is `HALF(5)` 2.5 or 2?

Comment: @irrelephant 2.5 ; edited question, thanks for catch.

Comment: @AdityaRajBhatt Then maybe n/2 and n*0.5?

Comment: @AbhishekBansal Doesn't that mean the same thing? Not just output-wise but otherwise too, like dividing by a number is the same thing as multiplying to its inverse. Like saying SUB()=x-y is same as SUB_new()=-1*(y-x). Sounds too "wimpy", umm like escaping the problem. Doesn't really reflect a new method. That could be it, but I would like to keep the question open for further comments. Especially to see if there are only _two_ ways possible.

Comment: @AdityaRajBhatt I wouldn't call this 'escaping' the problem. After studying the linked chapter, this seems a viable answer since one uses a divide function block, the other multiply. Ofcourse these will give the same answer since these are two ways of doing the same thing.

Comment: @AbhishekBansal Well, I suppose if you judge by output, yours is a valid solution to the problem, but again, I just don't feel too comfortable with it. Re-read at my previous comment. Anyway, even assuming that this is the right answer, can you think of another more "exotic" or clever one, which is still in the bounds of a beginner's lesson? If the question remains unanswered for a day, I will simply accept your answer.

Comment: @AbhishekBansal I believe it is what the book intended. One is (/ 2), the other is (* 0.5). Both `/` and `*` are shown previously, and various numbers were being used as inputs freely. No recursion had even been yet introduced, at that point.

Comment: @WillNess Bear in mind that `(/ n 2)` and `(* n 0.5)` typically will not return the same value in Common Lisp (unless `n` is already a float of some sort). `(/ 5 2)` is the rational 5/2 and `(* 5 0.5)` is the float 2.5.

Comment: @Vatine Right, in *Common Lisp*; but at that point of *that* book ......... :) he's just drawing boxes there. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's seems to be you are describing [peano arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_arithmetic). In practice it works the same way as doing computation with fluids using cups and buckets.

You add by taking cups from the source(s) to a target bucket until the source(s) is empty. Multiplication and division is just advanced adding and substraction. To halve you take from source to two buckets in alterations until the source is empty. Of course this will either do `ceil` or `floor` depending on what bucket you choose to use as answer.

```
(defun halve (x)
  ;; make an auxillary procedure to do the job
  (labels ((loop (x even acc)
             (if (zerop x)
                 (if even (+ acc 0.5) acc)
                 (loop (- x 1) (not even) (if even (+ acc 1) acc)))))
    ;; use the auxillary procedure
    (loop x nil 0)))
```

Originally i provided a Scheme version (since you just tagged lisp)

```
(define (halve x)
  (let loop ((x x) (even #f) (acc 0))
    (if (zero? x)
        (if even (+ acc 0.5) acc)
        (loop (- x 1) (not even) (if even (+ acc 1) acc)))))
```

Comment: haha most probably it works as it should, but I can't make heads or tails of it. Someone please close this question, I don't think there is any "beginner" answer to the question apart from /2 and *0.5. I understood your analogy perfectly and it sounds as repeated subtraction, but the code is beyond my grasp.
EDIT : Accepted the answer. This serves to tell me there are more than two ways and I have a _lot_ to learn. The code might as well be written in assembly though, for all it helps me. Still that is entirely my fault. Thank you.

Comment: @AdityaRajBhatt I didn't catch it was CL. updated the answer to a CL version for you.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Okay, lets see if I can describe this step by step. I'll break the function into multiple lines also.

```
(defun half (n) 
;Takes integer n, returns half of n
    (+ 
         (ash n -1) ;Line A
         (if (= (mod n 2) 1) .5 0))) ;Line B
```

So this whole function is an addition problem. It is simply adding two numbers, but to calculate the values of those two numbers requires additional function calls within the "+" function.

Line A: This performs a bit-shift on n. The -1 tells the function to shift n to the right one bit. To explain this we'll have to look at bit strings. 
Suppose we have the number 8, represented in binary. Then we shift it one to the right. 
 1000| --> 100|0 
The vertical bar is the end of the number. When we shift one to the right, the rightmost bit pops off and is not part of the number, leaving us with 100. This is the binary for 4. 
We get the same value, however if we perform the shift on nine: 
1001| --> 100|1 
Once, again we get the value 4. We can see from this example that bit-shifting truncates the value and we need some way to account for the lost .5 on odd numbers, which is where Line B comes in.

Line B: First this line tests to see if n is even or odd. It does this by using the modulus operation, which returns the remainder of a division problem. In our case, the function call is (mod n 2), which returns the remainder of n divided by 2. If n is even, this will return 0, if it is odd, it will return 1. 
 
Something that might be tripping you up is the lisp "=" function. It takes a conditional as its first parameter. The next parameter is the value the "=" function returns if the conditional is true, and the final parameter is what to return if the conditional is false.
So, in this case, we test to see if (mod n 2) is equal to one, which means we are testing to see if n is odd. If it is odd, we add .5 to our value from Line A, if it is not odd, we add nothing (0) to our value from Line A.

Comment: Yes I read something like this in the first few pages of Land of Lisp before I left it for Gentle Introduction. This was the particular technique which made me leave it. Didn't explain anything, just did it. That made me think the book is not for new people. Really interesting, but I still don't know how it works though.

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer. *Very* clear explanation, I wish I could accept two answers or even upvote this one. But I don't have even that much rep so, gratitude will have to do for now.